# Error 400 Invalid request with upload url but file is properly send to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I try to send a file to sharepoint using the Microsoft Graph API resumable file upload :

First, I create my upload session `POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/{itemid}/createUploadSession` and I get my upload url, no problem here.

I call my upload url `PUT: https://xxx-my.sharepoint.com/personal/xxx_onmicrosoft_com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/xxxxxxxxxx/uploadSession?guid='xxxx'&overwrite=True&rename=False&dc=0&tempauth=xxx` with some parameters: Content-Length and Content-Range

I get this error, code 400 : `{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Invalid request"}}` but if I take a look to my sharepoint, the upload did create it! I tried to add or remove parameters, change PUT to POST but of course, it's not working (got `DeferCommit was set to false for this upload session.`, which seems to be normal if I call the upload url with POST).

If I look to the error message, I just have `Bad Request` with no more informations. I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing. If you have some insights, please do tell!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was missing! I need to add this header to my request:  `Accept` with the value `application/json`. Now it works like a charm!